# DynamicSnitch Reads from empty new datacenter

Tags: cassandra

When adding a new datacenter the dynamicSnitch causes us to read data from the new dc when the data is not there yet.

We have a cassandra (1.0.11) cluster running on 3 datacenters and we want to add a forth datacenter. The cluster is configured with PropertyFileSnitch and DynamicSnitch enabled with 0.0 badness factor. The relevant keyspaces replication factor are DC1:2, DC2:2, DC3:2. Our plan was to add the new datacenter to the ring, add it to the schema and run a rolling repair -pr on all the nodes so the new nodes will get all of their needed data.
Once we started the process we noticed that the new datacenter recieves read calls from the other data centers because it has a lower load and the DynamicSnitch decides it will be better to read from it. The problem is that the data center still doesn't have the data and returns no results.
We tried removing the DynamicSnitch entirely but once we did that every time a single server got a bit of load we experience extreme performance degredation.

Have anyone encountered this issue ?
Is there a way to directly influence the score of a specific data center so it won't be picked by the DynamicSnitch ?
Are there any better ways to add a datacenter in cassandra 1.0.11 ? Have anyone written a snitch that handles these issues ?

Thanks,
Izik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bootstrap the nodes instead of adding to the ring without bootstrap and then repairing.  The former ensures that no reads will be routed to it until it has all the data it needs.  (That is why Cassandra defaults to `auto_bootstrap: true` and in fact disabling it is a sufficiently bad idea that we removed it from the example cassandra.yaml.)

The problem with this, and the reason that the documentation recommends adding all the nodes first without bootstrap, is that if you have N replicas configured for DC4, Cassassandra will try to replicate the entire dataset for that keyspace to the first N nodes you add, which can be problematic!

So here are the options I see:

1. If your dataset is small enough, go ahead and use the bootstrap plan
2. Increase `ConsistencyLevel` on your reads so that they will always touch a replica that does have the data, as well as one that does not
3. Upgrade to 1.2 and use `ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE` on your reads which will force it to never make cross-DC requests